# Proving a property of normal subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and let $G_1,G_2$ be subgroups of $G$ with $G_1\cap G_2= \{e\}$. Show that $G_1$ and $G_1$ commute if and only if they are normal subgroups. With $G_1G_2 $ defined as {$xy \in G : x\in G_1 , y\in G_2$}

1) I think they both need not be normal subgroup. If even one of them is normal they will definitely commute. (Tell me if I am wrong).

2) But I don't know how to prove they don't commute if both are not normal. Pls help me and thanxx for the help.

Comment: Alternating groups contain lots of disjoint commuting subgroups.

Comment: Does commute mean $G_1G_2 = G_2G_1$? Or $g_1g_2 = g_2g_1$ for all $g_i \in G_i$? Are you assuming $G = G_1G_2$ or not?

Comment: I will provide link to the $[question]( < https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~gill/CILASite/ >)$ Download the first book , chapter 1 (introduction to groups) part 5 , question 16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your claim is false. Take $G=S_n (n\geq 4),G_1=\lbrace id,(12) \rbrace, G_2=\lbrace id,(34) \rbrace$.

Then $G_1G_2=G_2G_1$ but neither $G_1$ nor $G_2$ is normal.

Comment: Could you prove your $G_1,G_2$ are not normal subgroups?

Comment: Sure. Let $g=(1324)$, then $gG_1g^{-1}\neq G_1$ and $gG_2g^{-1}\neq G_2$